# Conditional replace only functions on first row

Tags: r

I am making a summary data frame from multiple data frames. The code I am using works correctly to replace the first row in the new frame but does not work for any other row.

```
`tableCols<- 'Sessions, Pages/session, Session duration, Bounce rate, No. or return visits, Age, 18-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55-64, 65+, % Male, Device, Mobile, Desktop, Tablet, Affinity category, Movie Lover, TV Lover, Technophile, In-Market segment, Employment, Education Autos & Vehicles  '
tableCols<-strsplit(as.character(tableCols), ',' )
    Table<-data.frame(Dimension =unlist(tableCols), All_users = numeric(24),    Non_bounce = numeric(24))
    #this works and is in the first row
    Table$All_users[Table$Dimension=="Sessions"]<-sum(gaDatCY15$sessions)
    #this does not
    Table$All_users[Table$Dimension=="Session duration"]<-sum(gaDatCY15a$sessionDuration)`
```

I can run and print just the sum function the second time I use it and I get the correct value. However, it will not overwrite the value in the corresponding row in the new data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably that your Dimensions are factors but you expect them to be strings.  Try

```
tableCols<-
  gsub( 
    pattern = "^\\s",
    replacement = "", 
    x = strsplit(as.character( tableCols ), ',' )[[1]]
  )
Table<-
  data.frame(
    Dimension = tableCols, 
    All_users = numeric(24),    
    Non_bounce = numeric(24), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
```

I use **stringsAsFactors = FALSE** to prevent conversion to factors.  I hate stringsAsFactors.  First thing I learned from http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html was to use `str()` on one's variables anytime one finds them misbehaving.

Another thing I notice is that strsplit on commas was converting

```
'Sessions, Pages/session, ... '
```

to  [Sessions], [_Pages/session] ... note the underscore at the front of the second column name is actually a space.  I use **gsub** to strip the leading whitespace.

Comment: Changing the parse character to ", " from "," fixes the issue. Thank you for identifying that. When I have to work with lists I do not create (unlike this list) i will keep gsub in mind. Thank you for the quick reply!